# Reps vs timed sets

Tags: reps, timing

I have researched how you should measure time under tension when exercising instead of counting reps. However, I do not always have a timer with me and I was wondering if it would still be effective if I just did the number of reps I would normally achieve while exercising with a timer.

Comment: So, you're timing your set and you do 5 timed reps. The next day you forgot the timer but you know you only got 5 last time, so you just do 5 again? Are they at the same tempo?

Comment: I would do 5 again, but as fast as I could depending on my energy levels.

Comment: Why would you do them as fast as possible if TUT is the goal? Maybe you can expound on your timed training technique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer.

> If you do the same number of reps with the same tempo , yes it will be similarly effective

If you are not measuring time with a stop watch but with the reps , then the time under tension is reps * time taken for each rep , where time taken for each rep is the tempo.

If you don't have a timer either stay at a constant tempo or just count seconds like kids on the play ground instead of the reps.